# How to comletely remove all tracking cookies, and keep only Firefox's configuration setting?

Tags: firefox, cron, browser, cookie

I find it very difficult to manually deleting stored cookies from the system, without resetting the user settings in Firefox. And I am not even sure whether I delete all unnecessarily cookies from all folders.

I am thinking of finding a way to write a script or creating a cron job to automatically delete stored cookies, but I don't know what cookies from which folders should I work with without loosing the cookies that are in charge for the Firefox's user settings.

I see two folders where cookies are saved, in .cache/mozilla and in .mozilla.

Normally I block all cookies in Firefox and allowing only certain websites to place and read cookies.

Comment: What are the differences between these cookie types use that to create your script!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly your question, but Firefox create cookies related to the configuration settings only. Websites place similar cookies too. So I would like to delete any other cookies, but only keep Firefox's configuration ones. I see what you mean now, I should change the title of the question.

Comment: Please see this: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies

Comment: Thank you. So what are all these files that are created in the Firefox's folders? And also why the cache is keep growing, even that I have restricted all cookies to be blocked. And I've selected to delete all cache and cookies files in Fiirefox settings too. Can you please share another link which explains these files?  thanks. Seems like I miss core fundamentals  about these things, and that's why I struggle to understand about cookies and other files being stored in the system for so long time now.